# Payback Calculation with Two Variable

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have issue calculating Payback in excel and thus seeks a formula for the same:

```
A- Fixed Cost = 100,000 $ (Initial Investment)
B- Variable Cost = 5,000 $ (Monthly Expenditure)
C- Earning from Investment - 15,000 $ (Per Year Earning)
```

How to Calculate Payback in Years ???

Comment: What should the answer be?

Comment: Assuming that the monthly expenditure is the total for the year then a simple `=A1/(C1-B1)` would give you the answer.  but if it is the actual per month expenditure then as @garysStudent stated the answer is never.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, the answer is simple.  The monthly expenditure is *$5,000*, so the yearly expenditure is:

```
=12 * $5,000 = $60,000
```

and the yearly income is only $15,000

Therefore you will **never** break even!